# ! Extra \endgroup error

Tags: errors, pdf, miktex, compiling, compilation-error

After compiling my latex file using MikTek in Windows 10 using TexMaker, I get the following error.

```
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup
\let \BeforeStartOfDocument \@firstofone \cpt@beforest...
l.73 \begin{document}
```

The .pdf file is getting generated but cannot be seen in the built-in viewer of TexMaker. What should I be rectifying in my latex file?

Comment: You are using a package that uses `catoptions`, which doesn't work.  Please show a compilable example that demonstrates the issue

Comment: Either something in your preamble is incompatible with a current latex, or something is not up-to-date. But without a small but complete example it is not possible to say more.

Comment: Unfortunately, `catoptions` is broken with the current LaTeX kernel: it uses several tricks that heavily modify the standard behavior of LaTeX, so the fact it eventually broke was not unexpected.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A quick fix is to use `\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}` before `\documentclass[]{}`.

Comment: This fixed it for me, MikTek with TexStudio on Windows.  I tried the latest RevTex on MikTek, and I tried downloading directly from CTAN.  Nothing worked except this.

Comment: This works on overleaf when compiling COLI templates.

Comment: This worked for me with rQUF2e document class

Comment: This introduces the `hyperref` bug with `pageref` as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645757/pageref-gives-section-name-and-other-information). In my case, OP's error was being caused by the inclusion of the `xwatermark` package (`\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}`). Will not be using it, then.

Comment: This works, but what's the explanation behind this hack? I started having this issue a year ago or more, recently even updated my TexLive installation, and I still have it.

Comment: I really wonder why this bug is still alive in 2024.