# Why do I get Extra \endgroup. error with XeLaTex?

Tags: xetex

I am writing my Master's thesis using a LaTex template provided by the university. For the most part, I write locally and sync changes with an Overleaf project in order to collaborate with my supervisors. After getting almost the whole paper written, I can't even compile a simple example because of an "Extra \endgroup." error. I have reproduced the error [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qpgqzftfrfnc). It is view-access-only, so if you want to debug, please, copy the project (remember to use XeLaTex compiler).

I also include the code here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report} %openright
\usepackage{microtype}      % better looking text
\usepackage{fontspec}       % Package for custom fonts
\usepackage[]{geometry}     % Package for changing page margins (before fancyhdr) 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % Package to change header and footer
\usepackage{parskip}        % Package to tweak paragraph skipping (instead of indents a small skip is added after every paragraph)
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}           % Package for drawing
\usepackage{pgfplots}       % Package for creating graphs and charts
\usepackage{xcolor}         % Package for defining DTU colours to be used
\usepackage{amsmath}        % For aligning equations among other
\usepackage{siunitx}        % SI units
\usepackage{listings}       % Package for inserting code, (before cleveref)
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url} % Ability to line break urls at hyphens
\usepackage{hyperref}       % Package for cross referencing (also loads url package)
\usepackage{cleveref}       % improved cross referencing
\usepackage{textcomp}       % \textdegree = °C and other useful symbols
\usepackage[english]{babel} % localisation 
\usepackage{caption}        % better captions
\usepackage{subcaption}     % for subfigures
\usepackage{csquotes}       % For biblatex with babel
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex} % Package for bibliography (citing)
\usepackage{tabularx}       % for ability to adjust column spacing in tabular better
\usepackage{booktabs}       % for better tables
\usepackage{float}          % floating figures in correct places
\usepackage{calc}           % Adds ability for latex to calculate (3pt+2pt) 
\usepackage[printwatermark=false]{xwatermark} % Package for wartermark. Toggle printwatermark true or false to include or remove the watermark
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

main.log from my local machine can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/y5zK5Q1p).

I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581907/extra-endgroup-error) and the fix from the comments works for me, however, it introduces another error (see my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629770/how-to-use-pdfpages-with-pagecolor-using-xetex)).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't use the xwatermark package. It is incompatible with a current latex.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! If you add this as an answer I will mark it as the solution.
Could you point me to how can I check it myself without commenting out different parts of the code manually?

Comment: "commenting out different parts" is what I use to debug such problems, only in this case I already knew the cause from earlier questions.