# pageref gives section name and other information

Tags: fancyhdr, lastpage, pageref

tl;dr: \pageref{} gives section name and other info additional to pagenumber

I want to display the page numbers in my document in a "current page / all pages" form and defined

```
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage/\pageref{preLastPage}}
```

however, \pageref{} shows not only the page number, but also the section name and other info, so it displays:
4/122Discussionsection.6

same with other \pageref{} cases, eg when I want to refer to a part on another page:

```
For caption see page~\pageref{graph_abstract_caption}.
```

It displays: "For caption see page 33Introductionfigure.caption.10."

It seems to be a marker problem, but I did not redefine anything as far as I know.
I am using

```
\usepackage{nameref,hyperref,lastpage,fancyhdr}
```

In case I did mess with markers somewhere, how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short comilable TeX code resulting in your issue.Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: I guess this is part of my problem. I have a huge thesis with different parts and I do not know where this error is caused. When I compile from scratch just one section, the pagenumber reference is fine. If I add the next chapter, it is messed up, if I take it out again and only compile the first section, it is STILL messed up, although the previous compilation of the same part was fine. I do not understand where this problem comes from, was hoping someone has seen the problem before or has an idea based on the wrong information that is printed.

Comment: That is what `nameref` does. If you don't want it, remove `nameref` from `\usepackage`.  In itself `nameref` does it only with the use of `\nameref` but maybe your `\pageref` has been redefined to include some `nameref` stuff. If you remove `nameref`, you might get an error message that shows where that is done. Without your code, I'm just guessing, of course.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum that worked! thanks a lot!

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I am having the same exact problem as OP, and my setup is the same as hers (big thesis project with too many files to find an MWE), except I am *only* loading `hyperref`, not `nameref`. Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: @Mew, Sorry, I am on vacation now without a computer at hand, so I cannot dive into this problem.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum A little update: after some pruning, I have found that I can remove this effect by commenting out either of two(!) lines: `\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}` and `\usepackage{hyperref}`. I needed the former based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581907/extra-endgroup-error/581962#581962) thread, and hyperref is obviously necessary. Seems to be an ordinary bug.